# Does the use of semantic tags like header, nav, article, section, etc, have an effect on the page load?

Tags: html, pageload

I use semantic elements a lot while creating the page. Just wanted to check whether there are any page optimization benefits of using semantic elements.

Comment: Your file size increases because div has 3 letters and article 7. So ... Just kidding. I think there is no performance difference.

Comment: you should perform benchmarks to answer these questions for your specific use case.